# Find by post_meta, then sort by post_meta, then sort by date (wp_posts)

Tags: wp-query, order, sql

I have a custom meta field that I find a list of posts from. This custom meta is a numerical attribute (1-10) and I need to sort by 1-10, but I also need to sort by post date.

So if two items are both assigned a "1", then I need to fallback on post date (newest first).

I'm having a hard time ordering by the fields from two different tables.

This is what I've got so far...

```
$query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'cat' => $category_id,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'featured', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC' 
);
```

How can I take the above query arguments and sort by post date from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 4, you can order by multiple fields via an array:

```
'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC' )
```

Comment: Right, but I can't seem to orer by multiple fields of different tables.  I'm finding a list of posts from the wp_postmeta table, the publish date is stored in wp_posts

Comment: It doesn't matter that they're in separate tables, they're joined in the query. Edit your question to show the arguments you've tried and the value of `$your_query->request` after the query is run. I've tested the above in a query and it works as expected.